# JAVA - Get generic implementation of a class

Tags: java, generics

Imagine I have an abstract class defining a `Generic Type`. All subclasses will implement this Generic Type.

I can achive so by declaring a abstract method that forces the subclass to return that type. But is there a more elegant way to achieve this directly from the 'Class' object definition of the subclass?

```
public class GenericTest {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception{
        Class strClass = ClazzImplString.class;
        Class intClass = ClazzImplInteger.class;

        Class implTypeStr = ((AbsClazz)strClass.getConstructor().newInstance()).getGenericType();
        Class implTypeInt = ((AbsClazz)intClass.getConstructor().newInstance()).getGenericType();

        System.out.println("implTypeStr: " + implTypeStr);
        System.out.println("implTypeInt: " + implTypeInt);
    } 
}
abstract class AbsClazz<GenericType> {
    abstract Class getGenericType();
}

class ClazzImplString extends AbsClazz<String> {
    public ClazzImplString() {}    
    @Override  Class getGenericType() {return String.class;}
}
class ClazzImplInteger extends AbsClazz<Integer> {
    public ClazzImplInteger() {}    
    @Override Class getGenericType() {return Integer.class;}
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you after the `java.lang.Class` instance? Or is "`Class`" in your snippet a placeholder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass--).

```
ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) ClazzImplString.class.getGenericSuperclass();
Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
System.out.println(clazz); // prints class java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set the return type for your abstract method to be the `Class`, parametrized with the generic type:

```
abstract class AbsClazz<T> {
    abstract Class<T> getGenericType();
}
```

Then, in your subclasses, you will be *forced* to implement a method, that returns the type provided in the class definition. For example:

```
class ClazzImplString extends AbsClazz<String> {
    public ClazzImplString() {}    
    @Override Class<String> getGenericType() {return String.class;}
}
```

Comment: What I was tryng to avoid is the subclass being force to implement this method. Thanks for the reply anyway

Answer (score 2):

Here is one crazy hack with reflection:

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;

class GenericClazz<T> {
    public Class<T> getType() {
        return (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
}
```

(source - one of my old projects: [link](https://github.com/MightyPork/mightyutils/blob/master/src/mightypork/utils/Reflect.java))

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the `getGenericType` on each subtype getting `ParameterizedType` from subtypes.

An example look like this:

```
public abstract class AbsClazz<E extends Serializable> { }

public class ClazzImplInteger extends AbsClazz<Integer> { }

public class ClazzImplString extends AbsClazz<String> { }

public class GenericTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("implTypeStr: " + getTypeFromGenericClass(ClazzImplString.class, 0));
        System.out.println("implTypeInt: " + getTypeFromGenericClass(ClazzImplInteger.class, 0));
    }

    public static Class<?> getTypeFromGenericClass(final Class<?> genericType, final Integer index) {
        final ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) genericType.getGenericSuperclass();
        return (Class<?>) type.getActualTypeArguments()[index];
    }

}
```

This example will print:

```
implTypeStr: class java.lang.String
implTypeInt: class java.lang.Integer
```